# Error Installing imtools Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: compiling

When trying to install a tool for converting images to raw text format called [imtools](http://digitalpbk.com/projects/imtools-linux-command-line-tool-convert-images-one-format-another-jpeg-bmp-png) I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: trans.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [imtool] Error 1
```

I installed other required libraries like `libjpeg` but I can't resolve this error.

Makefile code:

```
object = image.o jpeg.o main.o bmp.o edge.o png.o stats.o trans.o raw.o

imtool:$(object)
    cc -o imtool $(object) -ljpeg -lpng -lglut
jpeg.o: jpeg.h
raw.o: raw.h
image.o: image.h
main.o: defs.h glx.h
edge.o: edge.h
trans.o: trans.h
png.o: png.h png.c
    cc -c png.c -o png.o -g
stats.o : stats.h
bmp.o: 
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm *.o
```

Comment: You probably need to link the standard math library as well i.e. add `-lm` to the end of your `cc` command for `imtool`

Answer (score 1):

I edited the makefile as follows:

```
object = image.o jpeg.o main.o -lGL -lGLU bmp.o edge.o png.o stats.o trans.o -lm raw.o

imtool:$(object)
    cc -o imtool $(object) -ljpeg -lpng -lglut
jpeg.o: jpeg.h
raw.o: raw.h
image.o: image.h
main.o: defs.h glx.h
edge.o: edge.h
trans.o: trans.h
png.o: png.h png.c
    cc -c png.c -o png.o -g
stats.o : stats.h
bmp.o: 
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm *.o
```

added `-lm -lGL -lGLU` and it's working fine now :)

Comment: The usual place for the libraries would be in the command line, not the object list i.e. something like `cc -o imtool $(object) -ljpeg -lpng -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm`